Problems getting square api to work on a phone app with .net Maui
Hi I’m trying to make a bookkeeping app with .net Maui and pull user data from a users square accounts and add them to the book automatically. The only issue is that it seems like o auth 2 for square needs a https url for the redirects. I am looking for any ideas on how to this.
So far I have tried ai, reading through the documentation, and now i am trying forums.
